# Syntax for Aggregating a Filtered Dataset in OData v4 Spec using $apply

Tags: odata, odata-v4

Suppose I am querying a dataset called `Sales` with the following schema:

`id (int)
price (decimal)
active (bit)`

Using the `$apply` query option and the `aggregate` transformation of the [OData v4 spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.html#_Toc378326289), what would be the syntax for finding the average price for only active Sales?

`$apply` supports both aggregation and filter transformations, but I can't figure out how to combine them or if you're even allowed to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$apply=filter(Status eq 1)/aggregate(price with average as averagePrice)
```

maybe you can refer the existing test:

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/test/E2ETest/WebStack.QA.Test.OData/Aggregation/AggregationTests.cs

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/test/UnitTest/System.Web.OData.Test/OData/Query/ApplyQueryOptionTest.cs

Comment: is there a way to get only top5 of the averageprice? I mean apply orderby>top to the results of aggregate