# OData v4: Trying to filter data before aggregating it

Tags: odata

I am trying to get some aggregated data from an OData endpoint V4 but before aggregating it I want to apply some filters. 
Here I have tried to set up the parameters separately but the aggregation is made for entire set of data

```
Products?$filter=(Category eq "Beverage")&$apply=aggregate(cost with sum as TotalCost)
```

However, I also tryed to put the filter in the $apply attribute as suggested in [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056941/syntax-for-aggregating-a-filtered-dataset-in-odata-v4-spec-using-apply)

```
Products?$apply=filter(Category eq "Beverage")\aggregate(cost with sum as TotalCost)
```

but I am getting the following error:

> Cannot parse 'filter' in apply

Answer (score 0):

The query below should work 
`Products?$apply=filter(Category eq 'Beverage')/aggregate(cost with sum as TotalCost)` 
By the way which version .NET/.NET core and EF/EF Core are you using?